# Convert .xlsx to csv

Tags: csv, type-conversion

I have a huge amount of .xlsx files that 1) I want to convert in csv and 2) merge into a unique file.
I found how to do the do #2, but I am missing #1.
I found some software on the web, but I am working on the firm's pc and I cannot install anything - I hope there is something through cmd or matlab.

Comment: why do we need to convert xlsx to csv, it still can be open by excel if you just change he suffix.

Comment: because 1) .csv files can contain much more lines than .xlsx
2) is easy to merge them all at once if you have a big number of .csv

Answer (score -1):

Use this script to convert .xlsx to csv through command line

https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv

Comment: How do I use it? Sorry I am not familiar with this kind of things, I only wrote manually in the cmd line once.